# Sitecore 8 implement tooltip on RTE authored content

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have a requirement to implement tooltips for words that are authored in Sitecore RTE.

The idea behind is that user should be able to hover over the word and see it's description/meaning.

Is this possible to achieve in sitecore? Did a quick search on marketplace but could not find any modules.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some options to consider for achieving what you described.

1. **Inject Tooltip HTML in a renderField pipeline**

   In this option, you would extend the `renderField` pipeline. First, you will need to ensure that you are dealing with a rich-text field, and if so, locate terms and replace them with the necessary markup that is required for the tooltip. This could be as simple as wrapping the word in an `<abbr>` or perhaps a `<span>` element with a CSS class. The list of terms and tooltip content could be sourced from items in Sitecore or a custom Sitecore Dictionary. Caching the terms would be essential as this pipeline processor is invoked frequently every time a field is rendereded.
2. **Progressive enhancement with JavaScript**

   This approach is almost entirely based on the client-side. Terms could be located and replaced fairly easily with the help of JQuery. If the list of terms is of a reasonable size, they could be bootstrapped into a JavaScript variable. Once terms are located and enhanced, a separate, asynchronous call to a REST endpoint could be made when hovering or clicking the term. The API would accept a term and respond with the term's definition.
3. **HTML Snippet in RTE Editor**

   Sitecore RTE editor can be extended with additional buttons. One of these options allows you to insert predefined snippets of HTML. The RTE editor also has a setting to specify a CSS file to style the content within the field (`<setting name="WebStylesheet" value="/css/yourstylesheet.css" />`). Styling would be necessary in order to target the description markup and make it visible to be edited, whereas, on the public site, the description markup would normally be hidden by default until the term is clicked on or hovered over.
4. **Dynamic Link Replacement**

   http://www.layerworks.com/blog/sitecore-token-replacement

Comment: There's an option to add link, where we can specify tooltips but leave the href to null.